# Add column to order grid in customer edit page - M2

Tags: magento2, admin, grid, customer-account, order-grid

How can i add new column in order grid in customer edit page?

I want to show custom columns records from sales table in order grid in customer edit page.

I found this file but also not able to overwrite:

**vendor\magento\module-customer\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\Tab\Orders.php**

[image]

Any help will be appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The data that shows there comes from sales_order_grid.

If you have data in sales_order you will have to join those tables.
In my example code below I did a test with remote_ip field from sales_order.
You can just replace your attribute there.

app/code/StackExchange/CustomerOrderGrid/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd"
>
    <preference for="Magento\Customer\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\Tab\Orders"
                type="StackExchange\CustomerOrderGrid\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\Tab\Orders"
    />
</config>
```

app/code/StackExchange/CustomerOrderGrid/Block/Adminhtml/Edit/Tab/Orders.php

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace StackExchange\CustomerOrderGrid\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\Tab;

use Magento\Customer\Controller\RegistryConstants;

class Orders extends \Magento\Customer\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\Tab\Orders
{
    private \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Backend\Helper\Data $backendHelper,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
        \Magento\Sales\Helper\Reorder $salesReorder,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $backendHelper, $collectionFactory, $salesReorder, $coreRegistry, $data);
        $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
        $this->coreRegistry = $coreRegistry;
    }

    public function setCollection($collection)
    {
        $collection->join(
            [ 'sales_order' => 'sales_order'],
            'main_table.entity_id = sales_order.entity_id',
            ['remote_ip']
        );

        parent::setCollection($collection);
    }

    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        $this->addColumn('remote_ip', ['header' => __('Remote IP'), 'index' => 'remote_ip']);

        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }
}
```